# Why $\liminf A_n=\{\omega\mid\omega \text{ in all but finitely many $A_n$}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Why $\liminf A_n=\{\omega\mid\omega \text{ that are in all but finitely many $A_n$}\}\ ?$

To me,
$$\liminf A_n=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcap_{m\geq n}A_m,$$

and thus, $$\omega \in\liminf A_n\iff \exists n\in\mathbb N: \forall m\geq n, \omega \in A_m$$
what would be $$\liminf A_n=\{\omega\mid\omega \text{ that are in all $A_n$ except a finite number of $A_n$}\}.$$
What's wrong in my interpretation ?

Comment: The only thing (linguistically) wrong is the words "that are" added in the set builder notation; this would read "... is the set of all $\omega$ for which $\omega$ that are in ..." -- To add a third semi-natural language variant: $\liminf A_n=\{\,\omega\mid\omega\text{ in almost all }A_n\,\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. The set of $\omega$ which are contained in all $A_n$ except a finite number of $A_n$ is equal to the set of $\omega$ which are contained in all but finitely many $A_n$.

Comment: Why these two sets are equals ?

Comment: "contained in all but finitely many" means "contained in all but a finite number of them" means "contained in all except a finite number of them"